# Show form when onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

This is my form. However, I would like to show it on onclick event. It has a button that says "sign up" and when you click it this form shows up, could anyone help me?

```html
<form action="action_page.php" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
  <div class="some_form">
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>

    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
    </label>

    <p>By creating an account you agree to our 
      <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.
    </p>

    <div class="clearfix">
      <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
    </div>`enter code here`
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showForm() {
  document.getElementById("signupForm").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#signupForm {
  display: none;
}
.buttonSignup {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="showForm()" class="buttonSignup">Sign up</div>

<form action="action_page.php" style="border:1px solid #ccc" id="signupForm">
  <div class="some_form">
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
    </label>

    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.
</p>

    <div class="clearfix">
      <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
    </div>`enter code here`
  </div>
</form>
```